# Upgrading Xpack license in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

In elastic Search 6.3.2, and Kibana 6.3.2, there is Xpack already installed with the package, but when i tried to access in Kibana, it threw license expired error. How should i upgrade Xpack version and I need to work on watcher. Please help me to upgrade the Xpack version.

Thanks, 
Gowri

Comment: what kind of license do you have? what do you get when running `GET _xpack/license` ?

Comment: hi, i clicked on license management in kibana, and started for a trial version, now watcher is available for one more month, so if i need to use it beyond that what should i do ?

Comment: At the end of the trial period, the platinum features (watcher, etc) operate in a [degraded mode](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/license-expiration.html). You can revert to a basic license, extend the trial, or [purchase a subscription](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions/). [more info](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/current/license-management.html)